# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of x

Tags: c#

```
public static MyViewModel CreateViewModel(Test entity)
{
    return new MyViewModel
    {
       Date = entity.Date,
       IsSelected = entity.IsSelected
     };
}

readonly MapViewModel _parent;

public MyViewModel (MapViewModel parent)
{
  _parent = parent;
}
```

I am getting the following error message, I could not able to figure out how to handle that. I would be glad if anyone has any ideas.

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'parent' of
>   'MyViewModel.MyViewModel(MapViewModel)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you don't explicitly specify a constructor for your `MyViewModel` class, it will assume that a parameter-less one will be used. However if you have a single view model as you currently do, you will need to explicitly create a parameter-less one as well (as MVC only knows of the one that expects a `parent` parameter) :

```
public MyViewModel()
{
     // Example of parameterless constructor
}

public MyViewModel (MapViewModel parent)
{
      _parent = parent;
}
```

Parameter-less constructors can also be incredibly helpful for MVC to know how to serialize content and bind it to your models as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rion, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyViewModel` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

```
public static MyViewModel CreateViewModel(Test entity, MyViewModel parent = null)
{
    return new MyViewModel(parent)
    {
       Date = entity.Date,
       IsSelected = entity.IsSelected
     };
}
```